# Create roles and users only in a certain database and not in the default postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to setup a database with a readwrite user `jirauser` and a readonly user `controlling_ro`. This is my script to set it up based on [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/) Blog article. `testuser` is the master user.

```
PGPASSWORD=XXX psql \
  --dbname=postgres \
  --host=XXX.XXX.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
  --port=5432 \
  --username=testuser \
<<EOF
-- Clean DB
DROP DATABASE jiradb;
DROP USER jirauser;
DROP USER controlling_ro;
DROP SCHEMA jiraschema;
DROP ROLE readonly;
DROP ROLE readwrite;

-- Create DB
CREATE DATABASE jiradb;
\connect jiradb;
CREATE SCHEMA jiraschema;

-- Revoke privileges from 'public' role
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE jiradb FROM PUBLIC;

-- Read-only role
CREATE ROLE readonly;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE jiradb TO readonly;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA jiraschema TO readonly;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA jiraschema TO readonly;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA jiraschema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readonly;

-- Read/write role
CREATE ROLE readwrite;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE jiradb TO readwrite;
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA jiraschema TO readwrite;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA jiraschema TO readwrite;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA jiraschema GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO readwrite;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA jiraschema TO readwrite;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA jiraschema GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO readwrite;

-- Users creation
CREATE USER controlling_ro WITH PASSWORD 'XXX';
CREATE USER jirauser WITH PASSWORD 'XXX';

-- Grant privileges to users
GRANT readonly TO controlling_ro;
GRANT readwrite TO jirauser;
EOF
```

After running this script I expect the roles and the users only to be in the `jiradb` database. However looking into the default database `postgres` with dbeaver they are also there. Does this mean they also have access to the `postgres` database?

[image: postgres screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just an artifact of your client tool.

In reality, PostgreSQL users don't belong to any database; they are shared by all databases. So no matter to which database you are connected when you create a user, it will equally exist for all databases.

You can use the `CONNECT` permission on the database object or (more typically) configure `pg_hba.conf` to determine which user can access which database.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html:

> CREATE ROLE adds a new role to a PostgreSQL database cluster. A role is an entity that can own database objects and have database privileges; a role can be considered a “user”, a “group”, or both depending on how it is used. Refer to Chapter 21 and Chapter 20 for information about managing users and authentication. You must have CREATEROLE privilege or be a database superuser to use this command.
>
> Note that roles are defined at the database cluster level, and so are valid in all databases in the cluster.

So it's just your GUI misleading you.